# Objective C syntax question

Tags: objective-c, programming-languages, syntax

I see that the UIColor class can call the variable like this [UIColor redColor];
How can I write my class to do the same thing? Also, can I have a method only for class, for example, like this:

[MyClass callingMyMethod];

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Just use a `+` instead of a `-` when declaring the method:

```
+ (void)callingMyMethod
{
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a class method. Class methods are defined like instance method, but have a `+` instead of a `-`:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
+ (id)classMethod;
- (id)instanceMethod;
@end

@implementation MyClass

+ (id)classMethod
{
    return self;    // The class object
}

- (id)instanceMethod
{
    return self;    // An instance of the class
}
```

Note that within a class method, the `self` variable will refer to the class, not an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are call class messages. Use `+` instead of `-` when defining a message.

Like this:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject 
{

}

+ (void) callingMyMethod;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `+` instead of the `-`. This is called a class method and is used to for initializing and return the object.

```
@interface SomeClass : NSObject
+ (id)callingMyMethod;
- (id)otherMethod;
@end

@implementation SomeClass

+ (id)callingMyMethod
{
    return self;    // The class object
}

- (id)otherMethod
{
    return self;    // An instance of the class
}
```